Can anyone identify what is this?
I’m trying to see how can I identify this by similar characteristics but it doesn’t look like bacteria nor protozoo. This is a sample from standing water.
For the third image there is a dissected “caterpillar” which looks like part of lepidoptera family.
If someone knows what is this, let me know.
Thanks for helping!




Can you add some more information about it? Where did you find it (Region), where did you take the sample...

The teacher took the water sample and brought it to class. I only know that she said that the sample we were working on was standing water. Unfortunately, I can't express more information about it because she didn't mention the details.

The first two pictures show air bubbles trapped between the slide and coverslip. The dots are condensation droplets.
The 3rd photo shows a larva of some sort, possibly a beetle, but I have no expertise on that area.
